# Haunted by KillerService.exe while attempting to get C# server & client programs to communicate (from same machine)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I made client & server programs in C# based on [this example code](http://technotif.com/creating-simple-tcpip-server-client-transfer-data-using-c-vb-net/).

Server program:

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(8080);
tcpListener.Start();
```

First time I ran this, Windows Firewall popped up and asked me if it should be allowed network access.

Client program:

```
IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(tbServer.Text);//"MyComputer-MSI"
string addr = ip.AddressList[0].ToString();
TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(addr, 8080);
```

At the last line above, I got the message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: No connection could be
>   made because the target machine actively refused it

I made sure both programs (Client.exe and Server.exe) were allowed by Windows Firewall. No other antivirus currently enabled (as far as I know).

Checked for conflicts with command `netstat -a -b`:

```
 [KillerService.exe]

  TCP      127.0.0.1:8080           MyComputer-MSI:0            LISTENING
```

The strange thing is that `KillerService.exe` (which I can't find in any of the tabs when I CTRL-ALT-DEL) changes its address to match whichever port I use for the server program.

Comment: That sounds like some kind of antivirus program.

Comment: It's this: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN131119/EN - 99% sure on that.

Comment: Are you sure `addr` is correct? Also, it’s probably cleaner to use the `IPEndPoint` constructor.

Comment: thanks for the responses. I just found a preinstalled program called "Killer Network Manager". Attempting to figure out how to add a program to its list.

Comment: yes. Matches the address of the "Server" program exactly

Comment: Not sure if anyone looking at this question anymore, but testing with some python code revealed that my server program is working fine.